# How use react-i18next withNamespaces in antd forms

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd, i18next

I am new in i18next an typescript, and i want translate an antd form using withNamespaces

```js
export default withNamespaces()(Form.create()(MyComponent));
```

This gives me the following error:

`Argument of type 'ComponentClass<RcBaseFormProps & Pick<any, string | number | symbol>, any>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ComponentType<WithNamespaces>'.
  Type 'ComponentClass<RcBaseFormProps & Pick<any, string | number | symbol>, any>' is not assignable to type 'ComponentClass<WithNamespaces, any>'.
  Type 'RcBaseFormProps & Pick<any, string | number | symbol>' is missing the following properties from type 'WithNamespaces': tReady, i18n, t`

what is the correct way to do this? Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone has the same problem can use `recompose` package.

https://github.com/acdlite/recompose

Then do something like this:

```js
import { compose} from 'recompose'

{...}

export default compose(withNamespaces())(Form.create()(MyComponent))
```